# Ember: session cookie from api not being set

Tags: cookies, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to set a session cookie from my back-end API for a particular ember-data model ('cart').

When createRecord is called on the model, I see the XHR "POST" request to my API.  I see the API process it and respond, and I see the Set-Cookie in the response headers...but no cookie in the browser!

The ember app and the api are on the same domain (localhost), though on different ports.  I googled and it appears that [cookies are not port-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific).  So I can't see what's preventing it.

I tried using the Chrome extension Postman to submit the same POST to the API and it works just fine - sets the cookie in the browser.  Just doesn't work when the request comes from the ember app.  Though I am not seeing any errors anywhere.

Is there something within ember that's preventing the cookie from being set?  I can't see why there would be, I think the browser should be processing the response headers before ember comes back into play.

I'm going down the rabbit hole of death on this!  Any help appreciated.  Here's the request/response.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use a different domain? In Chrome and sometimes Firefox cookie problems exist for localhost. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16328311/2471991) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583729/localhost-cookies-not-set)

Comment: That's a good thought - but still not working :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying a cross domain request you may have to grant permissions both on the app as well as on the server. Read on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) if that is the case. Also if you have [httpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookie, you will have to set withCredientials field in your ajax request as:

```
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
```

You can read more on withCredential [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials). These two are the major factors for cookie problems.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I spent more time than I'd like to admit on this.